# Binary Tree and Linked List:

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

Suppose I have the node classes:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, data, link=None):
        self.data = data
        self.link = link

class BTNode:

    def __init__(self, item, left=None, right=None):
        self.item = item
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

I want to create a linked list of the inorder traversal of the binary search tree.

What I have so far is:

```
def inorder(root):

    root = _inorder(root)[0] # return head of linked list

# helper function that returns the head and tail of the linked list. 
def _inorder(root):

    if root is None:
        return None, None

    else:
        temp = Node(root.item)
        if root.left:
            left_head, left_tail = _inorder(root.left)
            left_tail.link = temp
        if root.right:
            right_head, right_tail = _inorder(root.right)
            temp.link = right_head

        return left_head, right_tail
```

Test:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a1 = BTNode('A')
    a2 = BTNode('B')
    a3 = BTNode('C')
    a4 = BTNode('D')
    a5 = BTNode('G')
    a6 = BTNode('E')
    a7 = BTNode('F')
    a1.left = a2
    a1.right = a3
    a2.right = a4
    a4.left = a5
    a3.left = a6
    a3.right = a7
    x = inorder(a1)
```

However I get the error:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'left_head' referenced before assignment

If instead I do something like:

```
def _inorder(root):

    if root is None:
        return None, None

    else:
        temp = Node(root.item)
        #if root.left:
        left_head, left_tail = _inorder(root.left)
        left_tail.link = temp
        #if root.right:
        right_head, right_tail = _inorder(root.right)
        temp.link = right_head

        return left_head, right_tail
```

Then the error becomes: NoneType' object has no attribute 'link'
Can anyone see the problem because I think my logic is right.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case:

```
    if root.left:
        left_head, left_tail = _inorder(root.left)
        left_tail.link = temp
    if root.right:
        right_head, right_tail = _inorder(root.right)
        temp.link = right_head

    return left_head, right_tail
```

If you don't enter either of the ifs, you'll never have assigned left_head nor right_tail.

The second error is because of your first check:

```
if root is None:
    return None, None
```

Which given this assignment:

```
    left_head, left_tail = _inorder(root.left)
```

Will make both left_head and left_tail be None. Which causes the explosion you see in the next line.

Comment: Well, either check the return value of the _inorder call for the node with no children, or check that node.left != None before calling _inorder(node.left). Same for the right. I suggest you give it a try yourself and find out.